# OpenCL... still, or is it again

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, fglrx, amdgpu-pro

Ok so for weeks now i have been fighting with various versions of installing AMDGPU-PRO the installation goes fine but no luck with the card itself, just keep getting errors, BUT with persistence and lots of hunting, reading, installations, uninstallations i do feel i am getting a tiny bit closer to it actually functioning the way it should... or at least i though so, uninstalled the driver, reinstalled with all the relevant goodies and now it gives me the following error, very very little information about this around so hoping someone has run into this before and can help out... thanks in advance !!

```
owl182@owl182-BTC-T37:~$ clinfo
clinfo: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gallium-pipe/pipe_radeonsi.so: undefined symbol: amdgpu_query_video_caps_info
```

Comment: I got past the error, will post later on how, am not at that machine right now... unfortunately it did not help anyway, am talking to AMD support at the moment... will post if they have anything useful to say

Comment: How did you get past the error?